# How to write database module in nodejs

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, database

In my project, I am using MySQL database. The problem is, that I don't know how to write simple database module to one js file.

My code is:

File: database.js

```
var mysql = require("mysql");

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "localhost",
    user: "root",
    password: "",
    database: "mydb"
});

module.exports = class Database {

    constructor() {
        connection.connect(function (err) {
            if (err) {
                console.error(err);
                throw err;
            } else {
                console.log("Connection to database was successful");
            }
        });
    }

    getConnection() { return connection; }
};
```

I have a lot of files in project and each one needs use database, the problem is, when I import `database.js` constructor is every time called, I think, its a bad way.

Is there any better way how to use database connection in project? Somethink like call `getConnection()` from `database.js` file without call constructor.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Consider using a [_Singleton_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) for your database. You can also return an instance of a `Database` inside the module : `module.exports = new Database();`

Comment: Simply move the stuff inside the constructor outside of the class definition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A possible solution:

```
const mysql = require("mysql"),
      connection = mysql.createConnection({
          host: "localhost",
          user: "root",
          password: "",
          database: "mydb"
      });

connection.connect(function (err) {
    if (err) {
      console.error(err);
      throw err;
   } else {
    console.log("Connection to database was successful");
  }
});

module.exports =  {
  getConnection() { return connection; }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

In your database.js file while exporting write:

```
modules.exports = new Database();
```

And use

`require('./path/to/database-file')`

Wherever you have to use the instance, It will always get the same object.